# How to update SQL table with rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

So I have a database with name `web` and I have table in that database called `users` with rows `registered_time, updated_at` and etc. And now I want to add new rows in table `users`. Tried:

```
INSERT INTO  web.users (
    nick varchar( 32  )  DEFAULT NULL ,
    pug_rp int( 11  )  DEFAULT NULL
)

ENGINE  =  MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET  = utf8
```

But I'm getting error. What's wrong? Can anyone explain? Thanks!

Comment: show us the exact error message please

Comment: @scaisEdge updated first post

Comment: I think you are confusing columns with rows. Are you trying to add a user to the table or are you trying to add new columns (fields) to the table?

Comment: New columns to table :) @isaace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding a new column we need do use `ALTER`

```
ALTER TABLE `web`.`users`
ADD `nick` varchar(32)  DEFAULT NULL ,
ADD pug_rp int(11)  DEFAULT NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want insert a new user and your column name is username and  registered_time  you should use this sintax

```
Insert into `web`.`users`  (username,registered_time )
values (`nick`, '2018-01-29

Alias  Insert into tablename (col1, col2, ...)
values (val1, va2,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new row in the table "web.users" just do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO web.users VALUES('your_registed_time1', 'your_updated_at1', etc );
INSERT INTO web.users VALUES('your_registed_time2', 'your_updated_at2', etc );
```